# How to color parentheses with \left \right

Tags: mathjax

I want to color only the parentheses, but parentheses with `\left` `\right` conflict with `\color`.

I can color normal ones as following:

```
$$\color{red}{(}\frac12\color{red}{)}$$
```

While I can't figure out how to color this one:

```
$$\left(\frac12\right)$$
```

If I write:

```
$$\color{red}{\left(}\frac12\color{red}{\right)}$$
```

It will show an error:

```
Extra \left or missing \right
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't isolate `\left` from `\right` inside the arguments of other macros, like you are doing.  But you can change to red for the whole expression, and then back to black inside the parentheses, so they will be red and the fraction black.  Not as nice as being able to set the parentheses directly, but it might be sufficient for your needs.

Try

```
$$\color{red}{\left(\color{black}{\frac12}\right)}$$
```